# GEDCOM File import export from web application

Tags: gedcom

i am working on a social networking site having facility to create Family Tree.
there are so many sites which supports family tree import/export from GEDCOM File.
i have to implement family tree with gedcom standards. i also have to design my database as it should be capable to store data in a manner tht it can be exported to gedcom file as well as any gedcom file data can be imported in it...
i need some code samples which can do this.
if anybody have any idea about this please let me know

---

i found code from one blog from stackoverflow itself. i hope it can help me out
you can view it from this link
[Gedcom Reader for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836146/gedcom-reader-for-c)

Comment: Are you programming language agnostic? I mean, is it ok for the code samples to be in assembler? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

[PhpGedView](http://www.phpgedview.net/) does exactly this, and is open source.  You should be able to find plenty of code samples within the project.

Comment: i didnt work on php... i just worked in .net (C#,Vb.net)
i found php code as well as 2 projects from codeplex but i am unable to build them as some dlls are missing in it

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to java, you can use gedcom4j at http://gedcom4j.org.  It can read and write GEDCOM files in both the 5.5 and 5.5.1 format and stores the data in a java object graph so you can manipulate it as needed after loading/before writing.  You could also hook that into whatever database framework you want (I would never recommend GEDCOM as a database format, but it essential for data interchange).  There are plenty of ORM solutions to persist java object graphs to databases (hibernate being the one I'm most familiar with)

Answer (score 0):

This is a complementary answer about gedcom4j Frizbog. I am using gedcom4j java library.This library is very good and accurate .Only problem that I found is :http://gedcom4j.org/ at this time is down or does not exist and we cannot return to original documents and sample codes of the author. I could not find any address from Frizbog.At this time I only could read and update an gedcom instance I cannot to write a read gedcom 5.5 instance to a file.

Comment: And where is source code of gedcom4j 4.0.1 . I could see source code of 4.0.0 on github but no any source for 4.0.1